# Problem rosmak hector_quadrotor_demo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to rosmake hector_quadrotor_demo (I have ros fuerte with ubuntu 12.04.2) and I am getting this error:

```
gianluca@gianluca-Precision-T3600:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosmake hector_quadrotor_demo [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['hector_quadrotor_demo']                                          
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/gianluca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130524-140859            
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['hector_quadrotor_demo'] to:
['hector_quadrotor_demo']                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                          
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_msgs                                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                                             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs                                     
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface                          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                                              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs  No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> protobuf [ make ]                                                             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< protobuf ROS_NOBUILD in package protobuf                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                              
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
 No Makefile in package pcl                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test                                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]                                                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base                                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> hector_uav_msgs [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_to_tf [ make ]                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> hector_sensors_description [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< hector_sensors_description ROS_NOBUILD in package hector_sensors_description  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> laser_geometry [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< laser_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package laser_geometry                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> hector_mapping [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo                                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo_plugins [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo_plugins ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_plugins                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> hector_gazebo_plugins [ make ]                                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_to_tf [PASS] [ 0.38 seconds ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> hector_map_tools [ make ]                                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< hector_map_tools [PASS] [ 0.28 seconds ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> hector_nav_msgs [ make ]                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< hector_mapping [PASS] [ 0.68 seconds ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< hector_nav_msgs [PASS] [ 1.70 seconds ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> hector_geotiff [ make ]                                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> hector_trajectory_server [ make ]                                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< hector_uav_msgs [PASS] [ 3.21 seconds ]                                       
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesctor_gazebo_plugins: 3.4 sec ] [ hector_geotiff... [ 3 Active 59/67 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp:29:
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual gazebo::event::ConnectionPtr gazebo::UpdateTimer::Connect(const boost::function<void()>&, bool)’:
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:73:28: **error: ‘ConnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::UpdateTimer::Disconnect(const ConnectionPtr&)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:85:7: e**rror: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  In file included from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_imu.h:75:0,
                   from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_imu.cpp:57:
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual gazebo::event::ConnectionPtr gazebo::UpdateTimer::Connect(const boost::function<void()>&, bool)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:73:28: **error: ‘ConnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::UpdateTimer::Disconnect(const ConnectionPtr&)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:85:7: **error: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  In file included from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_gps.h:38:0,
                   from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp:29:
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual gazebo::event::ConnectionPtr gazebo::UpdateTimer::Connect(const boost::function<void()>&, bool)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:73:28: **error: ‘ConnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::UpdateTimer::Disconnect(const ConnectionPtr&)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:85:7: **error: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  In file included from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_sonar.h:39:0,
                   from /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:29:
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual gazebo::event::ConnectionPtr gazebo::UpdateTimer::Connect(const boost::function<void()>&, bool)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:73:28: **error: ‘ConnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::UpdateTimer::Disconnect(const ConnectionPtr&)’:**
  /home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/update_timer.h:85:7: **error: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.o]** Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/all] Error 2
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_imu.dir/src/gazebo_ros_imu.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_imu.dir/all] Error 2
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gianluca/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package hector_gazebo_plugins written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/gianluca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130524-140859/hector_gazebo_plugins/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< hector_gazebo_plugins [FAIL] [ 3.41 seconds ]                                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package hector_gazebo_plugins. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< hector_trajectory_server [PASS] [ 8.27 seconds ]                              
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package hector_geotiff written to:         [ 1 Active 60/67 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/gianluca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130524-140859/hector_geotiff/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< hector_geotiff [PASS] [ 12.52 seconds ] -- WARNING: 1 compiler warnings       
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Built 62 packages with 1 failures.                                                         
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                
[ rosmake ] /home/gianluca/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130524-140859                                 
gianluca@gianluca-Precision-T3600:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$
```

Any idea thank you in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63414/problem-rosmak-hector_quadrotor_demo/) by [jacobsolid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1909/jacobsolid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you cloned the groovy version from branch groovy-devel of the hector_gazebo stack from github. Please try again with the fuerte-devel branch, if you are using fuerte. The gazebo version that comes with groovy uses a newer API version and the groovy-devel branch will not compile any more with gazebo version 1.0.2 in fuerte.

We recently moved most of our tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg stacks from Google Code to GitHub (see https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg). The default branch is set to groovy-devel, so you have to specify the fuerte-devel branch explictly, e.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo.git -b fuerte-devel
```

or using [rosws](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html):

```
rosws set hector_gazebo --git https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo.git --version=fuerte-devel
```

Unfortunately the name of the development branch to use for each distro is currently not displayed in the ROS wiki. I opened a feature request issue [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/46).

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-05-26**:
Good answer! Just a minor typo: it should be --version=fuerte-devel, like this:

rosws set hector_gazebo --git https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo.git --version=fuerte-devel

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-05-26**:
Thanks, updated.

**Comment by [jacobsolid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1909/jacobsolid/) on 2013-05-27**:
Thank you very much it works!